# Variables type after math actions

Tags: java, variables, types

I have a question about variable types in Java.
If I have a long variable (called x) and an int variable (called y),
what's the type of (x/y)?

I've tried to use the "instanceof" option but it didn't helped me.

IMO It's long but I just want to be sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is some documentation .. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Answer (score 8):

A `long/int` is an `long` due to widening rules which is basically the result of any two values is the "widest" in terms of range of either of them.  Types `byte`, `short` and `char` are cast to an `int` in any operation with another number. (But not a String like `String + char`)

Note: `long % int` is also a `long` even though it couldn't possibly be outside the range of an `int` Similarly `int / long` is a `long` even though it can only be in the range of an `int`

Note2: `int * int` is still an `int` even though there is a good chance of an over flow.

You can only use `instanceof` on Object instances.  Primitives are not instances.

---

You might find these methods useful

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    System.out.println("2 / 1L is " + toString(2 / 1L));
}

public static String toString(boolean b) {
    return "boolean " + b;
}

public static String toString(byte b) {
    return "byte " + b;
}

public static String toString(char x) {
    return "char " + x;
}

public static String toString(short x) {
    return "short " + x;
}

public static String toString(int x) {
    return "int " + x;
}

public static String toString(long x) {
    return "long " + x;
}

public static String toString(float x) {
    return "float " + x;
}

public static String toString(double x) {
    return "double " + x;
}
```

prints

```
2 / 1L is long 2
```